# wysihtml5 - setting a value won't work, because 'sandbox iframe isn't loaded yet'

Tags: ajax, forms, wysihtml5

I'm just working on a little webservice. Therefore I am using an AJAX call and append my data to a table on my website. Here I can read and update already existing entries or write new entries. Everything works fine.

I want to have the possibility to update already existing with the wysihtml5 editor. I already integrated this editor on my website and I can use it on new entries. That works, too.

But now there's the problem with existing data. When it comes to the form to update data, I want the existing data being displayed as the value. Everything works fine on all inputs, just the wysihtml5 don't work.

I already know that there's an iframe and that's why I can't set the value of the textarea. I searched for a solution and found the following code (last line):

```
var editor = new wysihtml5.Editor("textareaid", { // id of textarea element
        toolbar: "wysihtml5-toolbar", // id of toolbar element
        parserRules: wysihtml5ParserRules, // defined in parser rules set
});

editor.setValue('Here's the content', true);
```

Usually this should work, but no content appears and the console just tells me:

Error: wysihtml5.Sandbox: Sandbox iframe isn't loaded yet

I tried it with a timeout-function but nothing works. Searching on the internet it also seems that there is noone else with that problem. I hope you can help me out, would be great!

Is there a way to set the value?

Comment: You can answer your own questions

Comment: one issue is the first `setValue` parameter is wrapped in single quotes, but has an apostrophe, which is the same as a single quote. Try `editor.setValue("Here's the content", true);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it working by myself. I just change the second parameter of setValue to false. I don't know why, but it works then.

Answer (score 8):

This code work for me

```
$("#product_details").data("wysihtml5").editor.getValue();// to get the value
$("#product_details").data("wysihtml5").editor.setValue('new content')// to set the value
```

Comment: I had another solution that worked for me but when I implemented this lightbox http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/ it killed it. Tried this solution and now it all works great.

Answer (score 5):

I got the solutions, below code worked for me

> $('#id ~ iframe').contents().find('.wysihtml5-editor').html(my_html);

Answer (score 3):

This work for me

```
$('.wysihtml5-sandbox').contents().find('.wysihtml5-editor').html(my_html);
```

the ".wysihtml5-sandbox" is a class name of iframe, create by wysihtml5 by default.

Comment: So, thats a simple copy of an older answer with a slightly modified jQuery selector in the first step. Is there anything that makes your solution a better one as the existing?

Comment: for beginner just want to copy this solutions.
no need to find what is iframe ID.

Comment: So, its even wrong understanding, because you are not using ID selectors in your answer

Answer (score 0):

this code worked for me :

```
 var wysihtml5Editor = $('#text_editor').data("wysihtml5").editor;
 wysihtml5Editor.setValue("<p>foobar</p>", true);
 console.log(wysihtml5Editor.getValue());
```